# Use a while loop if a condition is respected ,otherwise use an if statement

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use a while loop if a condition is respected , if that condition is not respected i want to use an if statement, How can i do that without repeat the code ?
there is the  algorithm ::

```
   if(condition){  
     while(otherCondition) {} 
   else if(otherCondition){}
  }
```

here is the situation : if a condition is true, i want to use a while loop, otherwise i want to use an if statement ::: replace the keyword "while" with the keyword "if" , while(){ } ==> if() { } and that depends on a condition is true or not ... i hope i am clear thanks for responding

Comment: Not easy to avoid repeating the use of `otherCondition` here as you will need to reevaluate it inside the while loop, so some duplication is to be expected with your criteria. You could, however, introduce a variable with a value based on `if(condition)`, and then inside the while-loop break off at the end if the value is not satisfied (which means you're still using a while-loop but it will at most run the statement block one time, aka an if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` is indistinguishable from a `while` that only executes once. Therefore, if you break the `while` after a single run, it behaves as if it's an `if`.

This means that you don't need to both define an `if` *and* a `while`. You can simply define a `while` and then ensure that (in some cases) the `while` gets broken after one execution.

Therefore:

```
while(otherCondition)
{
    // [your logic here]

    if(!condition)
        break;
}
```

If, for some unexplained reason, your `condition` must be evaluated before executing the loop logic (because the loop affects the outcome of `condition`), then simply evaluate `condition` before you start the `while`:

```
bool conditionWasMet = condition;

while(otherCondition)
{
    // [your logic here]

    if(!conditionWasMet)
        break;
}
```

---

I added a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rabr9M) to prove that the behavior between your code and mine is unchanged.

```
public static void Main()
{
    //YaminesWayOfDoingIt();
    FlatersWayOfDoingIt();
}

public static void DoJob()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing job"); 
}

public static void YaminesWayOfDoingIt()
{
    if(condition)
    {  
        while(otherCondition()) 
        {
            DoJob();
        } 
    }
    else if(otherCondition())
    {
         DoJob();
    }
}

public static void FlatersWayOfDoingIt()
{
    while(otherCondition())
    {
        DoJob();
        
        if(!condition)
            break;
    }
}
```

Regardless which method you use in `Main` (you can only use one, I kept the logic simple for clarity's sake), the output is the same.

Comment: that is not what i want to do, here is the situation :  if a condition is true, i want to use a while loop, otherwise i want to use an if statement ::: replace the keyword "while" with the keyword "if" , while(){ }  ==> if() { }  and that depends on a condition is true or not ... i hope i am clear thanks for responding so fast !

Comment: @YamineKlioui You're trying to do something that the language simply does not allow (i.e. dynamically swapping keywords based on a conditional expression). However, your intention will have a certain behavior based on the conditions. The code I showed you behaves the exact same way based on the exact same conditions, which means it enables you to achieve the goal you set out.

Comment: i am sorry, but that is not .. or i misunderstand something

Comment: yes i understand now, the behavior is what i want, but swap keyword dynamically could be useful too , anyway Thank you !

Comment: @YamineKlioui: I added a link to a dotnet fiddle that proves my code behaves the way your code does, but without having to repeat the logic (in my example, `DoJob()`).